# Browser detection using javascript failing on refresh

Tags: javascript, browser-detection

I'm trying to detect for devices that do not have support for **position:fixed**. EDIT: I've fixed the code so it's detecting features rather than browser/OS detection.

I think I was confusing people when I first typed this out. My issue is coming into play when I refresh the page. The height is being incorrectly calculated, which is a completely different issue I know, but am looking for assistance nonetheless.

Updated detection script below:

```
    function fixed() {
        var container = document.body;

        if (document.createElement && container && container.appendChild && container.removeChild) {
            var el = document.createElement('div');

            if (!el.getBoundingClientRect) return null;

            el.innerHTML = 'x';
            el.style.cssText = 'position:fixed;top:100px;';
            container.appendChild(el);

            var originalHeight = container.style.height,
                originalScrollTop = container.scrollTop;

            container.style.height = '3000px';
            container.scrollTop = 500;

            var elementTop = el.getBoundingClientRect().top;
            container.style.height = originalHeight;

            var isSupported = (elementTop === 100);
            container.removeChild(el);
            container.scrollTop = originalScrollTop;

            return isSupported;
        }

        return null;
    }


    //TEST FOR MOBILE, SET TOP IMAGE TO RELATIVE
    if(fixed()) {
        image_height = jQuery("#outer_homepage_image").height() - 45;
        jQuery("#content").css("top",image_height);

        jQuery(window).resize(function() {
            image_height = jQuery("#outer_homepage_image").height() - 45;
            alert(image_height);
            jQuery("#content").css("top",image_height);
        });
    } else {
        jQuery("#outer_homepage_image").css("position","relative");
    }
```

Comment: Did you know that you only have to write `jQuery` in its long form once? By wrapping your code in `(function($) { .... })(jQuery);`, you can use `$` no matter if `noConflict` has been used or not.

Comment: Why two separate if/else statements?

Comment: I did not and thanks for the tip @ThiefMaster Also I've fixed the double if statements in my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the support guys. I solved it with jQuery(window).load(function() {

it works now because everything else is loaded so I can calculate the proper height.

Answer (score 4):

This is an *extremely* brittle and ill-conceived thing to be doing.

```
if(/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
```

For example, iOS has fully supported position:fixed properly since iOS 4. We're now on 6. For Android & Blackberry, I'm not sure but would err on the side of "supported".

You need to test for **features**, not user agent. As I said, you could have one iOS device that doesn't support it and another one that does. Indeed, most do these days.

Here's a helpful link to lead you to moral, godly choices: http://kangax.github.com/cft/#IS_POSITION_FIXED_SUPPORTED